# Convert apple time stamp to Unix time

Tags: ios, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have a JSON file with a timestamp from an apple device that reads:

```
"timestamp":584507086.00054193
```

I want to convert it to other readable formats

Edit answer:

The format is called "Apple Cocoa Core Data timestamp". Added my answer bellow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I found a solution here:

https://www.epochconverter.com/coredata

This format is called "Apple Cocoa Core Data timestamp" made by apple

You just need to add `+978307200` seconds to convert it to Unix

Answer (score 0):

You can make this by next code:

```
let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: <#T##TimeInterval#>)
```

And then format your date

```
let format = DateFormatter()
format.dateFormat = "MMMM d"
let formattedDate = format.string(from: date)
```